# Scaling pgfplot axis with labels at end of axis

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following tikzpicture where the axis labels are anchored at the end of the axes. (code is at the bottom)

[image]

So far so good except that when I want to scale the axes (uncomment the line below), the labels goes off the supposed positions. In this example, it even fails when the x and y scales are set to the same value. (It works if I do `scale=0.7` in this case, but in general different scale factors might also be needed for the two axes)

[image]

Any suggestion on how this can be fixed please?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.17,
    mystyle/.style={
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
        every axis plot/.append style={mark = none, draw=black},
    },
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
       mystyle,
        xlabel=xlabel,
        ylabel=ylabel,
        % xscale=0.7, yscale=0.7  % uncomment this
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of  `every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west}`, use `xlabel style={anchor=west}`.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Would you like to make this an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: Any particular reason for using `scale` instead of setting the `width` and/or `height`?

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that to be honest. That might indeed be a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace

```
every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west}
```

with

```
xlabel style={anchor=west},
```

then using `xscale=0.7` works fine:

[image]

#### Notes:

- Axis labels were modified to be in math mode.
- Using `ymax=1.1` eliminated the issue of the dot being on top of the arrow.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.17,
    mystyle/.style={
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        %every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
        xlabel style={anchor=west},% <----- Revision
        every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
        every axis plot/.append style={mark = none, draw=black},
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
       mystyle,
        xlabel=$x$,% <----- Now in math mode
        ylabel=$y$,
        xscale=0.7, yscale=0.7,
        ymax=1.1,% <----- Added
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```